# Употребление глаголов выжать и отжать

Tags: лексика

Как правильно: отжать сок из лимона или выжать?

Answer (score 1):

Это синонимы .Выжать (разг.).

Comment: Спасибо! ))

Answer (score 1):

Из Ожегова:
ВЫЖАТЬ что. 1. Отжать(в 1 знач.), выкрутить (во 2 знач.).  В. белье. 2. Сжимая,  извлечь жидкость. В.  сок из лимона. 
ОТЖАТЬ 1. что.  Сжимая, туго  свертывая, удалить из чего-н.  влагу.  О. белье.

Судя по словарю, нейтральным, скорее, является ВЫЖАТЬ. Его прямое значение - выделить сок. А отжимаем мы лимон, отжать сок - это как бы смежное значение.

Comment: Спасибо!:)

Comment: Еще небольшое уточнение. Существуют два речевых варианта: (1) Мы ОТЖИМАЕМ лимон, чтобы получить сок. (2)Мы ВЫЖИМАЕМ сок из лимона.